# Spring Webflux: Remove WWW-authenticate header

Tags: basic-authentication, spring-webflux

I am using Spring 5 Webflux with Basic Authentication.

**Problem:**
When I type a wrong username or password spring reponses with Http Status 401 and includes the `www-authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"` Http Header which causes the browser to pop up the basic auth box.

How to remove that HTTP Header in Spring 5 Webflux?
Do I have to do a custom Webfilter?

Answer (score 1):

The code below is in Kotlin copied from my project. But the idea can be simply transfered into Java.

So the solution is tied around a custom Webfilter.

```
@Component
class HttpHeaderWebFilter: WebFilter {

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, next: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {

        return next.filter(exchange).then(Mono.defer {

            val headers = exchange.response.headers

            if (headers.containsKey("WWW-Authenticate")) {
                headers.remove("WWW-Authenticate")
            }

            Mono.empty<Void>()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: exchange.response.headers is ReadOnlyHttpHeader List, throwing exception

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following

```
if (exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey("headerKey")) {
    exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("headerKey", null, null);
}
```

We are using the double null, to overcome deprecated Overriding method.

If you are using Spring Framework 5.2, usage of single null is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it sends that header is that the authenticationFailureHandler associated with the default httpBasic() configuration uses the configured entryPoint. If it's not configured, then it uses the default entryPoint (HttpBasicServerAuthenticationEntryPoint) which adds that header to the response.

So, to change this behavior you can set a custom entryPoint, for example:

```
.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
```